# Parse findAllInBackground & fetchAllInBackground

Tags: android, parse-platform

i'm having an issue that soon enough going to blow me.

i have `Database` `table` lets call it `A`.   **table `A`** has field that determines if this `row` is processed or no.  i update the field myself from within the Parse `Browser` to either `True | False`, and trying to call `query.findInBackground()` to check with the `Boolean value` however the returned `List` always returns `False` if its `True` and vice versa. enough talking let me show you what i'm doing.

```
public static void getMyRequests(ParseUser user, final FindCallback<ServicesModel> callback) {
    ParseQuery<ServicesModel> query = new ParseQuery<>(ServicesModel.class);
    if (!user.getBoolean(ParseHelper.CAN_UPLOAD)) {
        query.whereEqualTo("user", user);
    }
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ServicesModel>() {
        @Override public void done(final List<ServicesModel> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                if (objects != null && !objects.isEmpty()) {
                    for (ServicesModel object : objects) {
                        object.setHandlerUser(object.getParseUser("handlerUser"));
                        object.setProcessedTime(object.getLong("processedTime"));
                        object.setCategoryType(object.getString("categoryType"));
                        object.setUser(object.getParseUser("user"));
                        object.setUserRequest(object.getString("userRequest"));
                        object.setImageUrl(object.getString("imageUrl"));
                        object.setProcessed(object.getBoolean("isProcessed"));
                        Logger.e(object.getBoolean("isProcessed") + "");
                    }
                    callback.done(objects, null);
                } else {
                    callback.done(null, new ParseException(1001, "No Services"));
                }
            } else {
                callback.done(null, e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

the `code` above suppose to `refresh` my `data` but however my log always shows that `isProcessed` is `False` even tho it's set to `True` inside the `Parse Browser`

what i have tried besides this? `fetchAllInBackground & fetch()` you name it. the object will always return `false` until i **re-run** the **application** from **`Android Studio`**   what i'm doing here wrong? btw here is how i initialize **Parse**

```
    Parse.setLogLevel(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? DEBUG_LEVEL : Parse.LOG_LEVEL_NONE);
    ParseObject.registerSubclass(ProductsModel.class);
    ParseObject.registerSubclass(ProductRentalModel.class);
    ParseObject.registerSubclass(ServicesModel.class);
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(context);
    Parse.initialize(context, context.getString(R.string.app_id), context.getString(R.string.client_id));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer was to remove

```
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(context);
```

which is bad anyway, without the datastore enabled the data are refreshed probably, however with enabling the `local database`, the data will not refresh unless if i killed the app and/or re-install it. that's bad. but did the trick.